# Combining two statements

Tags: javascript

How do I combine these two statements?

```
e.onerror=i3d;function i3d(a){a.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';}
```

`e.onerror` expects a reference to a function, but I just need to one statement as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'd hardly call it much of an optimization, you can assign the function directly to the event handler...

```
e.onerror = function() { /* do something */ };
```

Comment: true, it is a better way to do it, I don't know the best word

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
e.onerror=function(a){a.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';};
```